# undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass for simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this weird error coming suddenly, previously I was able to submit the data from one form to another .. I could not figure out what is going wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the view

```
<div class="choose-occasion">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <center>
        <img class="steps-img" src="/assets/choose-occasion/step-1.png">
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="heading-text">choose an occasion</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <%= simple_form_for @order, url: wizard_path,:method => :put do |f| %>
        <center>
            <%= f.collection_select :occasion_id, Occasion.all, :id, :name, {},{:class=> 'selectpicker btn-group'} %>
        </center>
        <input type="hidden" value="<%= spree_current_user.id %>" name="studio_order[user_id]" >
        <center>
                <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-primary continue-btn") do %>
                     Continue
                     <%= image_tag("choose-occasion/greater.png", class: "gmark") %>
                <% end %>
        </center>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller ..

```
class OrderDetailsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard

    steps :choose_occasion, :choose_style, :number_of_people, :choose_package, :upload_images, :instructions_artist

    def show
        byebug
        @order = StudioOrder.new 
        render_wizard 
    end


    def update
        byebug
        if StudioOrder.find_by(user_id: spree_current_user.id)
            @order = StudioOrder.find_by(user_id: spree_current_user.id)
            @order.update_attributes(getparams)
        end

        render_wizard @order
    end

    def getparams
        params.require(:studio_order).permit(:user_id, :occasion_id, :style_id,:initial_price, :number_of_people,
            :artwork_size, :package_id, :instructions)
    end
end
```

Here are the params going in

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"A64h4cyTdOuZji/2zSvr7K/WE3SZt2UMMP8bitsdY6c5Z2EA02qlJx/SKzE7yZT4lRMFPi8sDpJzSOi9m9NkLQ==", "studio_order"=>{"occasion_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"2"}, "button"=>"", "controller"=>"order_details", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"choose_occasion"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `'model_name' for nil:NilClass for simple form` means you don't have any data in your `@order` variable.

Because `form_for`/`simple_form_for` infers all of its data from the passed object, having no data prevents it from being able to populate its options (`model_name` etc).

---

The only issue I can see (I don't use `Wicked`) is...

```
#orderdetails#update
if StudioOrder.find_by(user_id: spree_current_user.id) #-> @order only set if user exists
  @order = StudioOrder.find_by(user_id: spree_current_user.id)
  @order.update_attributes(getparams)
end
```

The conventional pattern here is...

```
def update
   @order = StudioOrder.find_by(user_id: spree_current_user.id)
   <<do something>>if @order.update getparams
end
```

I *presume* that since you're using `Wicked`, perhaps re-rendering the form will not work properly if you don't have the `@order` variable in place. To fix it, I would remove the `if` logic:

```
#orderdetails#update
def update
  @order = StudioOrder.find_by(user_id: spree_current_user.id)
  @order.update_attributes(getparams)
  render_wizard @order
end
```

If you definitely needed to authorize the `spree_current_user`, you'd need to embody the entire flow with the logic, not just the `@order` declaration.

Comment: Actually those are the steps .. :choose_ocassion, :choose_style, .. are the views ..  this choose_ocassion is sending the user_id .. so from the next step each form goes to update method, and will fetch the row which has the user_id which is sent by choose_ocassion, and will try to update that row only. Actually the code was working, until I completed 3 steps, and felt that 4 rth form is complicated,went to 6th step, Now all the steps are failing :sob:

Comment: Hmmm, do you have any exceptions raised etc in the console?

Comment: Do you mind  taking a look here https://gist.github.com/vamsipavanmahesh/8c5f185848dc1b182ee5

Comment: It's saying the same as what I wrote; you're using `update` with a condition which prevents `@order` from being populated.

Comment: People like you going too far for solving some one else's problem is what makes SO great. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: can you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503354/how-to-handle-multiple-orders-for-an-user @Richard

Comment: Sure, let me take a look!