# How to handle multiple orders for an user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In my view there is a query like this ..

`<%= CaricatureType.find_by(id: StudioOrder.find_by(user_id: spree_current_user.id).style_id).name %>`

The schema for studio_orders and caricature_types is as follows

```
create_table "studio_orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "occasion_id"
    t.integer  "style_id"
    t.integer  "number_of_people"
    t.string   "artwork_size"
    t.integer  "package_id"
    t.text     "instructions"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.float    "initial_price"
    t.float    "final_price"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.json     "avatars"
    t.integer  "address_id"
  end
```

```
create_table "caricature_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.float    "price"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

Now the question is, the query in the view I have posted above comes in order_summary screen, and the query simply outputs the name of the style he has choosen. **Now the thing is, technically there can be many rows in the studio_orders with the same user id.** `But how to display the current style the user has choosen in the order_summary screen.`

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to put *any* `ActiveRecord` declarations in your view. All of that should be handled by the controller:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @types = CaricatureType.find_by(id: StudioOrder.find_by(user_id: spree_current_user.id).style_id).name %> 
  end
end
```

This has two benefits:

1. All your logic is kept in one place
2. `ActiveRecord` will reuse the data if it's called multiple times through an `@instance_variable`

---

For your specific issue,

> But how to display the **current** style the user has choosen in the `order_summary` screen

This is for you to determine.

Ideally, you'd want to put a `current` column in your `studio_orders` table. Assigning the type `boolean` to this column will allow you to use the following:

```
@current_type = CaricatureType.find_by id: spree_current_user.studio_orders.style_id, current: true
```

Rails might value [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) - but you're free to construct your schema / models as you see fit. This includes setting a `current` column if you need it.

Comment: can you check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624199/how-to-handle-the-ruby-like-interpretation-in-js?noredirect=1#comment58931257_35624199 @richard