# How to handle the ruby like interpretation in JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

```
var current_style = $('.current-style').data('style');
var current_package = this.id
$('.dp').attr('src', '<%= image_path("choose-package/#{current_style}-#{current_package}.png") %>');
```

My file name is **file.js.erb**. I am hoping that #{current_style} and #{current_package} will undergo string interpolation. But it is not really the case. The error I am getting is

```
undefined local variable or method `current_style' for #<#<Class:0x007f19b02bdda8>:0x007f19ba0c5ca8>
```

So I tried to remove the var in front of js variables, hoping that they would be assumed as ruby variables. Still no luck.

Comment: You can't use ruby interpolation here. Use regular javascript string building (`"choose-package/" + current_style + "-" ...` or something)

Comment: still this `$('.dp').attr('src', '<%= image_path("choose-package/"+current_style+"-"+current_package+".png") %>');` does not work @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Ah right, it's in the image_path and the ERB block. You'll have to get rid of those too. Use pure JS. You get values on the client side, there's no ruby there.

Comment: An alternative is to post style/package as parameters to the action that renders `file.js.erb` (so that they _are_ available to ruby as `params[:current_style]`, for example)

Comment: But I will be be able to get this current_package only with JS. How to handle this in params ? @SergioTulentsev

Comment: but you cannot change the image of a rails tag in pure JS right? @SergioTulentsev

Comment: there's no such thing as "rails tag". There are rails helpers for html tags. They generate html tags. Which you can manipulate from JS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104535/discussion-between-gates-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Comment: This is called interpolation and is not just for Ruby but all languages to a degree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're trying to call the `JS` variables inside the `Ruby` code block.

---

Whilst there is whole other issue of the validity of using `image_path` et al in `JS`, the immediate point is that you have to make sure your JS vars are being read as such; not Ruby vars...

```
var current_package = this.id;
var current_style = $('.current-style').data('style');
$('.dp').attr('src', '<%= image_path("choose-package/' + current_style + '-' + current_package + '.png") %>');
```

The above *should* resolve your path issue. Whether it's valid in the context of your app is another question

Comment: Hi Richard, can you please look into this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465118/injected-form-field-dynamically-in-simple-form-does-not-get-submitted can you please look into this